# how to set default working directory in vim and cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, gvim

My system is gvim 7.4+xp+cygwin.

Everytime i open vim or cygwin,input pwd

pwd in cygwin to get :
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/sy

I want to set the default directory /cygdrive/c/workspace
pwd in gvim to get :
c:/Documents and Settings/sy

I want to set the default directory c:/workspace
How can i make the setup in vim and cygwin?

1.i created a file named .bash_profile ,add two lines 
cd /cygdrive/c/workspace
echo "hallo world "

no effect at all.

2.i add `cd /cygdrive/c/workspace`  in the file `profile`,the wrong output is :
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: $'\r': command not found
': not a valid identifier
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: /etc/profile: line 104: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''

'bash: /etc/profile: line 104:`profile_d ()
-bash-4.1$

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Do you want the Cygwin terminal to start in the /cygdrive/c/workspace directory? You refer to both vim and gvim. Are you using the Cygwin or the Windows versions of vim and gvim?

Answer (score 0):

For Cygwin, put

```
cd /cygdrive/c/workspace
```

in ~/.bash_profile.

Or, maybe what you want to do is to make /cygdrive/c/workspace your home directory; by default that's where a Cygwin shell will start.  To do that, edit the entry for your user in /etc/passwd.  Then restart the Cygwin shell.

For gvim, create a shortcut to start gvim, right-click on it, go to Properties..., then enter C:/workspace in the "Start in" field.

Comment: there is no  .bash_profile  in cygwin,how can i do?

Comment: If you don't have one yet, create it.  It goes in your home directory (which is what `~` means).

Comment: I added a description of how to change your home directory - maybe better.

Comment: i created a file named .bash_profile and add two lines `cd /cygdrive/c/workspace` and `echo "hallo world " `, no effect at all.

Comment: If .bash_profile is in your home directory and bash is your shell, it will run it when it starts.